# Prove that if $(a,b)=1$ then there exist some $m,n$ such that $a^m+b^n\equiv 1 ($mod $ab)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if $(a,b)=1$ then there exist some $m,n$ such that $a^m+b^n\equiv 1\pmod {ab}$. Number $a$, $b$ are nature and positive number.

Since $(a,b)=1$  then there some number $x$, $y\in \mathbb Z$ such that $ax+by=1$. Since $(a,b)=1$ then I can use Fermath's theorem $a^{b-1}\equiv 1 \pmod b$, and $b^{a-1}\equiv 1 \pmod a$ so then $a^b\equiv a \pmod {ab}$ and $b^a \equiv b \pmod {ab}$. So $a^b+b^a\equiv a+b \pmod {ab}$. But I am not so sure that I going in right direction. Can you help me?

Comment: raise both sides of $ax+by=1$ to the $ab$ power, or something like that

Comment: How do you mean, you say that I need to use $x+y|x^n+y^n$ or something else?

Comment: no, just use binomial theorem to expand

Comment: @mathworker21 Hint: $\,\bmod ab\!:\ (a\!+\!b)^{\large n}\equiv a^{\large n} + b^{\large n}.\,$ See my answer for details.

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić We can do it directly without CRT - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, you need to find $m$, $n\in\Bbb N$ with
$a^m+b^n\equiv1\pmod a$ and $a^m+b^n\equiv1\pmod b$. That is
$b^n\equiv1\pmod a$ and $a^m\equiv1\pmod b$. By the Fermat-Euler theorem,
you can take $n=\varphi(a)$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

$\overbrace{(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow(\color{#c00}{ab},a\!+\!b)=1}^{\Large (\color{#c00}a,a+b)=(a,b)= (\color{#c00}b,a+b)},\ $ so $\,\bmod \color{#c00}{ab}\!: \overbrace{\exists\, n\!:\ 1 \equiv (a\!+\!b)^{\large n}}^{\Large{\rm e.g.}\,\ n\ =\ {\rm ord}(a+b)}\!\equiv \underbrace{a^{\large n} + b^{\large n}+\overbrace{\color{#c00}{(ab)}(\cdots)}^{\large \equiv\ 0\ }}_{\large \rm Binomial\  Theorem}$